# Do While Loop and If Statements - Where to position

Tags: vb.net

Previous to my other question, I now have another item I need to resolve with my **Do while/if statements**.

```
strSQL = "exec sp_CoursesStartingSoon"
    objConn = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
    objConn.Open()
    objCmd = New SqlCommand(strSQL, objConn)
    rsData = objCmd.ExecuteReader(0)

    While rsData.Read()

        If (rsData("subject") = "F23") Then

            html += "<h1>Access to HE</h1>"
            html += "<p>" & rsData("name") & "</p>"
            html += "<p>" & rsData("level") & "</p>"

        ElseIf (rsData("subject") = "F06") Then

            html += "<h1>Art and Design</h1>"
            html += "<p>" & rsData("name") & "</p>"
            html += "<p>" & rsData("level") & "</p>"

        End If

    End While
```

Now the issue I have is that I need the **H1** titles to only appear once, currently they are within the **While** loop so are looping  on every row. Can anyone provide a suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: use a StringBuilder to have your data much faster. It would be nice if you explained just a little what you are trying to achieve. If you want something to happen only once, use a boolean to remember you did it. If you want it to happens once per name, use a HashTable to remeber names having allready been processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- your stored procedure returns the items ordered by `subject` field
- and you have many items for subject=F23 and subject=F06
- you need to build a list of the same items grouped by subject

  ```
  Dim titleF23 as String = "<h1>Access to HE</h1>"
  Dim titleF06 as String = "<h1>Art and Design</h1>"

  While rsData.Read()

      If (rsData("subject") = "F23") Then
          if titleF23.Length > 0 then 
               html += titleF23
               titleF23 = ""
          end if
          html += "<p>" & rsData("name") & "</p>"
          html += "<p>" & rsData("level") & "</p>"

      ElseIf (rsData("subject") = "F06") Then
          if titleF06.Length > 0 then 
               html += titleF06
               titleF06 = ""
          end if
          html += "<p>" & rsData("name") & "</p>"
          html += "<p>" & rsData("level") & "</p>"
      End If

   End While
  ```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines but didn't quite have it down. Many thanks for the help, massive help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create another if for the h1 titles so that if you have printed it once you dont print again. Its a bit more costly but it would be a quick fix.